# Pegar diretório para salvar arquivo

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, e nesse sistema, eu gero um relatório em PDF a partir de algumas informações, eu gostaria de saber, como que faço para abrir uma tela parecida com o `filedialog`, mas para selecionar somente o diretório, para que quando gerasse o relatório, o usuário selecionasse onde vai ser salvo o relatório, como se fosse aquelas janela de selecionar onde você vai baixar um arquivo, qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: a aplicação não consegue salvar na maquina cliente... no máximo direcionar para download e então o navegador toma conta.

Comment: Se tem que enviar o arquivo via download ou via e-mail !!!

Comment: Ah sim, pesquisei aqui como fazer isso, e consegui resolver, obrigado